# row-level security in LLBLGenPro

Tags: database, security, llblgenpro

Has anyone ever done row-level security in LLBLGenPro?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the authorization framework?

[Generated code - Setting up and using Authorization](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/gencode_authorization.htm)

Comment: It looks like it offers just authorization events, but not implementation.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The authorization framework is the easiest way to implement row level security in LLBLGen AFAIK.

Comment: Of course it doesn't implement it, as everyone needs a different way to do security: AD, DB server, thread principal... The authorizer simply calls you to authorize an action, you tell it 'allow it' or 'deny it', and that's it. Using dependency injection, it's setup as simple as it can be, you can even add it to an application in production, using DI and a config file change.